# Disability Insurance - Limitation While Outside the United States or Canada

Tags: insurance, long-term-disability, disability

One thing that's very important to me about DI is that it doesn't restrict its coverage area to just within US & CA. Since I will have the policy for 20 years, given the current trend of globalization, I have no idea where I'll be residing within these 20 years.

I am currently residing in US. In the off chance that I get disabled while not living in US & CA, I want to still be covered and receive payments.

My agent searched all major U.S. insurance companies. Most have this "Limitation While Outside the United States or Canada" that states the applicant has to be within US or CA to be able to file claims, or that they have to stay in US or CA to continue receiving payments.

The only one that doesn't explicitly states this is MassMutual.

Should I take this lack of statement as an indication that MassMutual allows claims to be filed even if the insured resides outside of US/CA?

Comment: Surely that is a question for your agent and/or the insurance company itself.

Comment: I did ask both, but knowing that both are motivated to just sell me the insurance. I'd like to get a second opinion here just in case I miss anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible to give a second opinion without reading through the actual contract to see if there is some other limitation in the policy you are considering that would apply.  If you're not satisfied with the impartiality of your agent or the insurance company, you can certainly pay a lawyer to review the contract for you and provide advice.  But it probably isn't possible for someone on the internet who hasn't reviewed the contract to give you any sort of meaningful second opinion.

Comment: Does the limitation reference at time of disability.  Generally a residency limitation applies the the prospective insured's eligibility to buy the insurance not a restriction on the definition of disability.